# table not displaying html page

Tags: asp.net, html, css, xhtml, frontend

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserCreation.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserCreation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <title>ePay</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body 
         {
              height:100%; 
              margin:0; 
              padding:0; 
              overflow: hidden; 
              width:100%;  
              background-position:center;
              background-repeat:no-repeat;

        }

      #page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}

        #content {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px;}

        .leftAlignment
        {
            padding-left:10px;
        }

        .heading
        {
            padding-left:10px;
            color:#7a7474;
            font-size:20;
        }


        .content
        {
            padding-left:10px;
            padding-top:20px;
        }


        #background img{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 0;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        #bodywrap {
                position:absolute;
                width: 94%;
                margin-left: 3%;
                margin-right: 3%;
                margin-top: 10px;
                z-index: 20;
        }
        #backdrop {
                position: absolute;

        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding-top:10px;">
             <div id="background">
                    <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="Background Image"/>
            </div>
<div id="bodywrap">
    <div id="backdrop">
    <span class="heading" > User Creation </span></div>
    <div class="leftAlignment" ><img src="images/line.png" width="600"/></div>
    <div class="content">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <br />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Panel ID="PanelUser" runat="server">
    <table border="0" align="center" style="position:absolute;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Employee ID:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TexEmpID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    ontextchanged="TexEmpID_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Employee Name:</td>
            <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextEmpName" runat="server">       </asp:TextBox>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TexEmpID" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextUserName" runat="server">      </asp:TextBox>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TexEmpID"   EventName="TextChanged" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToCompare="TextPassword" ControlToValidate="TextRePassword" 
                                    ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Re Type Password:</td>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextRePassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsInactive" runat="server" Text="   Inactive" 
                                            Width="108px" />
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TexEmpID" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btSubmit_Click" 
                    Text="Submit" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
            </td>

        </tr>



    </table>
    </asp:Panel>

        </div>

     </div>
    </div>
  </form>
    </div>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The table is suppose to display an HTML page?

Comment: @ngen yeahit sud.i have put table there but when i load the page it does not display. :(

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your browser's Error Console? Does the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) find any errors?

Comment: @sarnold Nop. i guess the prob is with the css. i juz checkd it only with html n css without asp. it gives me the same result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is here. The problem is this line in your css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

It makes the scrollbar hide if one is needed. If you change it to:

```
overflow: auto;
```

and scroll a little, you'll see your table. The rest is up to you in order to position all the elements properly.